# Javascript array grid object property serialized by Kendo is null on server

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid that I have an editable detail template.  In the detail template, I have a multiselect.

When I save, I am manually updating the dataItem to grab the most up to date options in the detail template's multiselect.  There is no problem with grabbing the data from the multiselect.  Everything actually looks pretty good until I trigger the grid to save.

I add the multiselect items to the grid's dataItem with this code:

```
function SaveRefItemSubCategories() { //Called on Save button click
    var grid = $("#RefItemSubCategoryGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    for (var i = 0; i < grid.dataSource._data.length; i++) {
        var dataItem = grid.dataSource._data[i];
        dataItem.RefItemCategoryServiceIDs = [];
        var ms = $("#MultiSelect_" + dataItem.uid).data("kendoMultiSelect");
        var values = ms.value();

        for(var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
            dataItem.RefItemCategoryServiceIDs.push(values[i]);
        }
    }
    grid.dataSource.sync();
}
```

At that point, when I look at what is posted to the server, the grid's dataSource looks like this for the serialized multiselect items:

> models[0].RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[] 15
>
> &models%5B0%5D.RefItemCategoryServiceIDs%5B%5D=15

It should look like this:

> models[0].RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[**0**]    15
>
> &models%5B0%5D.RefItemCategoryServiceIDs%5B **0**%5D=15
>
> Sorry for extra space in there, I couldn't get it to bold otherwise

The lack of the array's index in the serialized data results in that property being null when it hits the server.  this property's type is List

I have tried a couple different approaches, but the end up creating new properties on the dataItem that stick around and cause problems after I save for the first time.

Some examples I've used instead of the push() method are:

- This one does send the data back, but it ignores the existing list and creates a new dataSource property for each array index.  This would work if I was only saving once, but if I save the grid multiple times, then the properties added stick around and mess with data integrity.  I would entertain this option if a way to 'reset' the dataSource was possible after saving (without reloading the grid).

  dataItem["RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[" + i + "]"] = values[i];
- This one had the same effect as the .push(), which is the property on my object on the server being null

  dataItem.RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[i] = values[i];

Please let me know if I can provide any more information and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not confident that this is the best way to handle it, but I have puzzled out a way that works.

I changed adding to the data item's properties from this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) { //values is array from multiselect
        dataItem.RefItemCategoryServiceIDs.push(values[i]);
}
```

to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { //values is array from multiselect
            dataItem["RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[" + i + "]"] = values[i];
}
```

Just this change works for every scenario EXCEPT this:

1. Save row with 2 options chosen from multiselect, resulting in 2 properties being added to the dataItem.  We'll say the ID's of those items are 1 and 21.  Posted data looks like this:

   models[0].RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[0] = 1
   models[0].RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[1] = 21
2. After saving, if we open that multiselect again and delete the first option (the one with ID 1), we get the following data posted:

   models[0].RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[0] = 21
   models[0].RefItemCategoryServiceIDs[1] = 21

Which is obviously not right (should just be 1 entry with the ID set to 21).  This is happening because the RefItemCategoryServiceIDs isn't really an array, just properties whose names look like array entries so that they serialize into a list on the server (as I understand it).  To mitigate this issue, I preceded the code that maps the current multiselect values to delete the existing properties associate with this array:

```
function CleanDataItemLists(dataItem) {
    if (dataItem.RefItemCategoryCarrierIDs != undefined && dataItem.RefItemCategoryCarrierIDs.length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        //Continues to remove properties by index until none are left
        while (dataItem.RefItemCategoryCarrierIDs[i] != undefined) {
            delete dataItem["RefItemCategoryCarrierIDs[" + i + "]"];
            i++;
        }
        //Cleans up empty array property
        delete dataItem.RefItemCategoryCarrierIDs;
    }
    return dataItem;
}
```

After this function is called, you can execute the for loop code referenced above and the data serializes with an index present (See initial post for example of missing index in serialized data), allowing the server to map it to the list object.  Like I said, I'm not convinced that this is the best way to do this, but it does work for me.  Hopefully, this can help someone else or lead to an even better answer.